# Can you get the caller DLL or executable module from the callee

Tags: c++, winapi, reverse-engineering

I only want to allow specific DLLs to execute code I have written on a function I hooked. short of performing a stack trace how do you get the module name of your caller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a stack trace to find the return address of your function, for instance with [`CaptureStackBackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633.aspx).

And then call [`GetModuleHandleEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx) passing `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` to obtain the module handle containing that code.

Finally, call [`GetModuleFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx) to find the filename associated with that module.

Comment: CaptureStackBackTrace looks promising. Is it a reliable way of getting the caller?

Comment: Well stack tracing is an imperfect art. On x86 at least the ABI doesn't enforce rules that allow perfect stack tracing as I understand it. In practice it's rare to be executing code that is so wacky as to confuse decent stack tracers. Since it is your code you should be safe.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this, but keep in mind that it will not provide a robust security mechanism.  It would be easy for a malicious process to fake a call from your DLL.

Comment: Also try `_ReturnAddress()`